# How to import nano/couchdb to nestjs project?

Tags: couchdb, nestjs, couchdb-nano

I have trouble importing and using Nano library for CouchDB in nestjs, or I am doing it wrong.
The URL needs authentication credentials.

I need to know a safe way and a practical way to start with CouchDB in a nestjs app (maybe some npm package that will do the heavy work). Also, in ASP.Net Core, for example, there is a connection string property in the appsettings.json. Is there something like that can be done with nesjs and Couchdb (URL with credentials and everything required to connect to couchdb), something like a configuration file for the database connection?

Isn't there a module to import, or is it not necessary?

Maybe I can't see the forest for the trees.